# Sum two fields from different tables when the results are a sum and multiplication in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this two queries and I want to sum their results in one query, but union all is not working.

I use this query:

```
select sum(a.value1) from myTable a
```

and I get: `10`, then I use this query

```
select b.value2*b.value3 from myTable b
```

and I get:`10`,I want to sum them and get `20`, so I use union:

```
select sum(a.value1) from myTable a
union all
select b.value2*b.value3 from myTable b
```

But the query returns

```
10
10
```

How I can sum them to get `20`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
select ((select sum(a.value1) from myTable a) +
        (select b.value2*b.value3 from myTable b)
       ) as sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!! 
select (sum(a.value1)+(select sum(b.value2*b.value3) from myTable b )) as test  from myTable a

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly could using this query:

```
select a.value4 + b.value5
  from (select sum(a.value1) value4 from myTable) a,
       (select b.value2 * b.value3 value5 from myTable) b
```